# save python output to shell variable, similar to perl -e

Tags: python, shell

Here is what I am trying to do but I want to use python instead:

```
test=$(perl -e 'print "test"')
[webalert@localhost scripts]$ echo $test
test
```

Is there a python equivalent for perl -e ? Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ test=$(python -c "print 'hello'")
$ echo $test
hello
```

(as a side note...)
If you want to preserve newlines, use quotes in the `echo`:

```
$ test=$(python -c "for i in range(3): print 'hello'")
$ echo $test
hello hello hello
$ echo "$test"
hello
hello
hello
```

One final tip:

Perl lends itself to one liners a bit better than Python does. I tend to do something like this rather than coerce python into being a language it is not:

```
$ test=$(python -c "
> import math
> import sys
> 
> for x in sys.argv[1:]:
>    print '2pi R of {}={}'.format(x,float(x)*2*math.pi)
> " 1 2.4 5 6.6)
$ echo "$test"
2pi R of 1=6.28318530718
2pi R of 2.4=15.0796447372
2pi R of 5=31.4159265359
2pi R of 6.6=41.4690230274
```

Comment: Thx so much, works like a charm! Do you happen to have the man link for this?

PS. I am just doing some simple date formatting, since all my scripts are in python I wanted to also use python in my shell script instead of perl. 1 dependenc is better than 2 :)

Comment: This is what I am doing: python -c 'import datetime; now=datetime.datetime.now();print "/{0:04d}/{1:02d}/{2:02d}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day)'

Comment: In perl its much cleaner, perl -e 'print strftime "%Y/%m/%d",localtime time-86400;'

Comment: **I** am the man! (i.e., I wrote this, and I do not know where you would find it exactly ;-) `man python` for the command line options. For what you describe, I would just use perl... Or use the python you have there. If I have a Bash questions, I usually go to [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)